# Linq query generates different result in SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, left-join, sql-server-profiler

I wrote this left join in LINQ and I only selected `PersonId` from `SHPerson` table, but in SQL Server profiler, I got `PersonId` from `SHPFA` table too.

```
 var spfQuery = from n in shHPFARepository.GetAll()
                                      .AsNoTracking()
                                      .Where(t => t.ShareCount > 0)
                group n by new { n.PersonId } into nGroup
                select new 
                { 
                    nGroup.Key.PersonId, 
                    TotalhareCount = nGroup.Sum(t => t.ShareCount) 
                };                                                                                       

 var query = (from sp in SHPersonRepository.GetAll().AsNoTracking()
              join spf in spfQuery on sp.Id equals spf.PersonId 
              select new SHPOutputDto
             {
                 PersonId = sp.PersonId,
                 ShareCount = spf.TotalShareCount,
                 IsShareHolder=true
             });

var resultDto = await query.ToListAsync();
```

I don't want `SHPFA.PersonId` ([t0].[PersonId]) being selected in query.

```
SELECT [t0].[PersonId], [t0].[TotalShareCount], [e].[PersonId]
FROM [SHolders].[SHPerson] AS [e]
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT [t].[SHPersonId], SUM([t].[ShareCount]) AS [TotalShareCount]
     FROM [SHolders].[SHPFA] AS [t]
     WHERE [t].[ShareCount] > 0
     GROUP BY [t].[PersonId]) AS [t0] ON [e].[Id] = [t0].[PersonId]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you would like to remove it from the sub select inner join or want to remove it from the final select result? Because seems like you are using two similar columns `[PersonId]` and `[SHPersonId]`

If this is only a typo thing then you should use `[SHPersonId]` in your first query, like this:

```
var spfQuery = from n in shHPFARepository.GetAll()
                                  .AsNoTracking()
                                  .Where(t => t.ShareCount > 0)
            group n by n.SHPersonId into nGroup
            select new 
            { 
                SHPersonId = nGroup.Key, 
                TotalhareCount = nGroup.Sum(t => t.ShareCount) 
            };
```

P.S.: don't forget to modify the second query by renaming `PersonId` to `SHPersonId`

Comment: I want to remove [t0].[PersonId] from the final select result

Comment: Did you try removing the `PersonId = sp.PersonId` line from then final query `select new SHPOutputDto`? I have a feeling we are misunderstanding each other...

Comment: no. the SHPOutputDto is what I want to see in output but I'm getting two PersonId in SQL Server profiler, the first PersonId is for SHPFA table([t0].[PersonId]) and the second PersonId is for SHPerson table([e].[PersonId]). I don't want the first PersonId being selected([t0].[PersonId]).

Comment: gotcha! I was able to understand the REAL problem... :D this problem seems to be a SQL profiler bug. Maybe the issue is related to the EDMX. Could you try removing and readding the table inside the EDMX? I know that is not so easy but it's worth a shot!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can always use [raw sql query](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx):

```
using (var ctx = new YourContext())
{

    var spfQuery = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<YourModel>("SELECT
         [t0].[TotalShareCount]
       , [e].[PersonId]
       FROM [SHolders].[SHPerson] AS [e]
       INNER JOIN 
          (SELECT [t].[SHPersonId], SUM([t].[ShareCount]) AS [TotalShareCount]
           FROM [SHolders].[SHPFA] AS [t]
           WHERE [t].[ShareCount] > 0
           GROUP BY [t].[PersonId]) AS [t0] ON [e].[Id] = [t0].[PersonId]"
    ).ToList();
}
```